# Css issue - Width of elements driving me crazy

Tags: css, width

So, I am a very proficient css problem solver, I know this because Ive done it hundreds of times, and normally I can find what the issue is very quickly.
I have an issue Ive been asked to look at that I want to shoot with a bazooka, I can NOT solve it for the life of me.

The site is www.ahml.info

When you load the site on a normal size screen with full width browser, everything looks fine:
[image]

But if you shrink the browser window to half size or so, the site looks awful:
[image]

For some reason the width of the divs that hold the top banner, footer etc, will only be as wide as the browser width.. Ive used chrome inspector to change the css of sooo many elements (that is normally how I find the issue) but nothing will force the width to be full.

Ive messed around with viewport, body width, div id & class widths and even gone as far as to remove all script calls in head section to be sure this is not somehow done after the dom loads. Nothing has fixed the issue and I cant solve this. Any help would be so appreciated..

Thank you, Jason

Comment: Forgot to add one piece of info. If you look at that site on mobile, it goes responsive and looks great. On the footer there is a link that says view desktop site, this makes the site non responsive but has the issue of the top not being wide enough YET if you used the browsers native request desktop site feature, the site looks normal.. How can that be? I thought all that button did was change useragent.

Comment: I don't see the situation you're describing. There are other problems though, such as the fact that the main slide show partially overlaps the calendar below it on certain widths. Are you sure it's not a matter of CSS caching on your end?

Comment: The red banner at the top should always be 100%, you should never be able to scroll past it and see any white.. You cant replicate this issue?

Comment: Oh, when scrolling to the right! Sorry, missed that. Well, something is overflowing the body, but I can't see what it is. However, if you give `overflow:hidden` to the body, the horizontal scrollbar disappears. Would that be a solution?

Comment: The banner at top fills the browser for me, but the site doesn't center with a smaller screen size. Could there be an issue with a media query?